# Changing textview's value using 2 seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

I have 2 seekbars for setting up a timer one for hours and 1 for minutes. I want to show the total duration of the timer by getting the progress of the 2 seekbar and inserting it in 1 textview with a hh:mm format without using any button.

here are my seekbars:

```
 hseek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int shours;
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                shours = progress;
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            hours = shours;
        }
    });
  mseek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int smins;
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            smins = progress;
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mins = smins;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the progress value of both of the seek bars in two variables, set the textview's text in `OnStopTrackingTouch` in both of the listeners
like this

```
yourTextview.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, mins));
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that I can do that. Sorry for asking a noob question